# Consequences of type I error and type II error?

Tags: statistics

A concert venue is located 4 minutes from a large university. A group of students are planning to attend the concert and think they can get there in less time. They test this hypothesis by using social media to survey a sample of other drivers to see how long this trip took them.
The null and alternative hypotheses are given.

....

Here is the full question:

[image]

Can someone break down how to solve this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The null hypothesis is that the mean time to get there is $4$ minutes against the alternative that it takes less than $4$ minutes to get there.

A type I error is when you reject the null hypothesis when the null hypothesis is actually true.

A type II error is when you fail to reject the null hypothesis when the alternative hypothesis is true.

Can you go from here?

Comment: Got it. Thanks!